# Unity Error CS1503 Convert double to float

Tags: unity-game-engine, double, converters

When i get a double from p und want to convert to float i get the error :  error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'string'. When i look at the output from Masse(double) i get the Number 0 (default value); I dont now why

```
foreach (GameObject p in Planetss)
{
y = 0;
vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
float distanz = Vector3.Distance(p.transform.position, vertices[i]);
double Masse = p.AddComponent<Value_Planet>().Masse1;
float FMasse = float.Parse(Masse);
```

Comment: Well `float.Parse` doesn't take s double but a `string` ...

Answer (score -1):

answer was easy

float Masse = (float)p.GetComponent<Value_Planet>().Masse1;